# How to fold custom region in CLion through comments?

Tags: ide, comments, clion

I read this:

https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/help/folding-and-expanding-custom-blocks.html

and tried following this link:

https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/help/Folding_Custom_Regions_with_Line_Comments.html

but it appears to be broken, since it redirects to "Meet CLion" page.

How do I define custom folding regions in CLion using comments?

Comment: Using the answer of Chloride Cull, you will need to have a new line between `//region` and the code that you want to place in that region. That's how I got it working.

Answer (score 24):

CLion is based on IntelliJ IDEA, and thus supports multiple ways, including:

```
//region Description
//endregion
```

and

```
//<editor-fold desc="Description">
//</editor-fold>
```

These can be easily accessed by selecting the code you wish to wrap in a region, and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. You can alternatively access it by clicking `Code` > `Surround with...` in the menu bar.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't seems to work for me. The surrounding works - but there's no way to fold it, the little plus/minus sign isn't there 

Comment: @arieljannai ran into the same thing, but it was fixed when I added a newline after the `//region` flag

Comment: You can now also use `#pragma region name`/`#pragma endregion` which also works in Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code.