# (Clion, macOS) Highlight specific parts of a code

Tags: c++, macos, background-color, clion

Is it possible to highlight particular parts of a code such as follows in Clion (macOS):

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight"? Why do you need it to be "highlighted"?

Comment: And while you can [create regions for folding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995741/how-to-fold-custom-region-in-clion-through-comments) I'm not sure it's possible to add custom "highlight" for such regions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I also didn't find an option to highlight a certain part of the code. Why do I need it... for a pro programmers it probably won't make much sense, but I thought it would make the code clearly arranged.

Comment: Regarding the "clearly arrange" bit... You can add empty lines to split the code into paragraphs, and use comments to explain each "paragraph". And maybe refactor the code to pull it out into a separate function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know, I do that. Still, I was wondering whether highlight a section of code is also possible.